# Ef Core 3.1 DbSet from another library

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I need to be able to use a class from an outside library in a `DbSet`. Every time I try to run Add-Migration I get the below exception.

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Type' from assembly 'assembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

All of the other posts I have read refer to adding `assembly.MigrationsAssembly` in the options builder. But this doesn't help in my case because I cannot move my DbContext to the other library. Does anyone know if it is possible to have a DbSet from another library?

Thank you,
Travis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need your models in a separate library than your DB Context. You need to copy the dll to the bin folder of the project that you will be performing the `Add-Migration` on.